# intuition behind tightness of measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

What is the motivation behind the definition of tightness of probabilty measures (given below)? Wikipedia says:

> The intuitive idea is that the given collection of measures does not "escape to infinity"

What does it mean to escape to infinity?

Let $(S,\mathcal{S})$ be a measure space, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mathcal{M}_{1}(S)$ denote the space of probability measures on $S$. A subset $\mathcal{R}$ of $\mathcal{M}_{1}(S)$ is said to be $\textit{tight}$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists$  compact set $K_{\epsilon}$ such that $\mu(S-K_{\epsilon}) < \epsilon, \forall \mu \in \mathcal{R}$

Comment: An Example: The sequence of measures on $\mathbb{R}$: $\mathrm{d}\mu_n=1_{[n,n+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x$ escapes to infinity.  The measure of any bounded (equivalently compact) set is 0 in the limit, so the weak(-star) limit isn't a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Never mind my last comment; brain fade.

Comment: I interpret this as saying the measures can be well-approximated by compact sets, which allows you to treat them as though they are bounded.